# MagicZoom and JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, zooming, magiczoomplus

I am trying to get MagicZoom and MagicThumb to work inside a JQuery dialog. Nothing at all happens when I mouseover the image, clicking on the same image take you to the image itself. So it seems as though the magic zoom javascript is not getting invoked.
The following code works elsewhere.

Here is the code

```
<a href="302734901.jpg" title="Blah" id="zoom1" rel="zoom-width: 330px; zoom-height: 408px; thumb-change: mouseover" class="MagicZoom MagicThumb">
<img src="302734901_small.jpg" alt="style #302734901 metal poly 'Levin.Ludwig' hooded windbreaker" class="special" width="340" height="408">
<span>Blah Blah</span>
</a>
<img class="MagicZoomLoading" src="/magiczoomplus/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading Zoom, please wait">
<div class="zoomInstruction">&nbsp;mouseover to zoom or click to enlarge&nbsp;</div>
```

Please let me know if anyone has tried this successfully.
Thanks,
Natasha

Answer (score 2):

Call `MagicZoom.refresh();` after loading the AJAX Content.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the apostrophes from the alt tag in the img.

Also try removing the class="special".